# How to mock pg in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, unit-testing

I am new to mock concept and javascript programming either. I want to to mock pg (postgres module) in the javascript program. I can imitate very simple scenario, but in actual I don't.

Here is my userHandler.js:

```
var pg = require('pg');
var connectionString = process.env.DATABASE_URL || 'postgres://admin:admin@localhost:5432/mydb';

exports.handlePost = function(req,res){

  var results = [];

  // Grab data from http request
    var adata = [req.body.Username, ..., req.body.FaxNum];  //Ignore for short.

  // Get a Postgres client from the connection pool
  pg.connect(connectionString, function(err, client, done) {

        // SQL Query > Insert Data
        var func_ = 'SELECT Dugong.Users_Add($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19)';
        var addUser_ = client.query(func_, adata);

        addUser_.on('error', function(error){
            var data = {success : false, 
                        username : req.body.Username,
                        reason : {errmsg : error.detail,
                                    errid : 'addUser_' }};
            return res.json(data);
        });

        addUser_.on('end',function(result){
            var data = {success : true, username : req.body.Username};
            console.log('Insert record completed');
            return res.json(data);
        });

    // Handle Errors
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
      return ;
    }
    return;
  });
};
```

And here is my unit test file. m_users_page.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var test = require('unit.js');
var mock = require('mock');
var httpMocks = require('node-mocks-http');
var real_users_page = require('../routes/users_page.js');

var b = mock("../routes/userHandler.js", {
    pg: {
        connect: function (connectionString,callback) {
                    if(connectionString === 'postgres://admin:admin@localhost:5432/skorplusdb'){
                        console.log('333');

                        //pseudo object
                        var client = {query : function(func_, adata, cb){
                            cb(null,adata);
                        }};

                        client.on('error', 'test emit the error in my mock unit.');

                        //pseudo done object
                        var done = function(){};
                        callback(null, client, done);

                        return ;
                    }
      }
  }
}, require);

describe('Test with static login', function(){

    it('Test simple login', function(done){
        var request  = httpMocks.createRequest({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/users',
        body: { Username:"Je", ..., FaxAreaCode:'232'} //Ignore for short
    });

    var response = httpMocks.createResponse();

        b.handlePost(request,response, function(){
            var data = response._getData();
            console.log("7777777777" + data);

            done();
        });
    }); 
});
```

Here is the error :

```
$ mocha testing/m_users_page.js


  Test with static login
333
    1) Test simple login


  0 passing (7ms)
  1 failing

  1) Test with static login Test simple login:
     TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'on'
      at Object.mock.pg.connect (testing/m_users_page.js:22:14)
      at Object.exports.handlePost (routes/userHandler.js:30:6)
      at Context.<anonymous> (testing/m_users_page.js:63:5)
```

My questions are:

1. What is a proper way to do a unit test in Node + Express + Mock + node-mocks-http?
2. How to find good framework with well document I must read. After several days, I started to circling around the result from search engines. They are too simple, I can't adapt it to my problem.

Comment: It's *extremely* hard to do in a general way because queries change the database state. The exact same query text and parameters can return different results based on unrelated queries executed in between or concurrently.

Comment: @CraigRinger . Thank you for your response. Now I know how hard it is now. I'm still wandering for solution so far.

Comment: People usually just use a real database with some test data in it. Sometimes that's the same engine as their production database (strongly recommended IMO). Sometimes it's a small embeddable one like HSQLDB or Derby. In general you can't really expect to mock large complex stateful interfaces. If you can simplify your interactions with it enough you could look at the stateful-mocking support in some mocking frameworks. No idea of the mocking framework you're using has any such support.

Comment: @CraigRinger . Thank you for you response. I got the order to do a test. Actually I myself will test with actual database and taking note in paper.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you understand the difference between *unit* tests and *integration* tests. If you want to test against the actual db, even if it has a dummy data set, that's an integration test and it doesn't need a mock: just connect to the database with the dummy data.

But suppose you want to test your webserver module, and you want to mock the db. First, pass the database module as a *parameter* rather than requiring pg directly. Also, wrap the postgres interface with your own class:

```
const { Pool } = require('pg');

module.exports = class DatabaseInterop {
  // Connection parameters can be passed to the constructor or the connect method, parameters to
  // DatabaseInterop::connect will override the initial constructor parameters.
  constructor ({
    user,
    password,
    database,
    host,
    logger={log: console.log, err: console.error},
  }) {
    this.logger = logger;
    this._params = {
      user,
      password,
      database,
      host,
    };
  }

  connect (params) {
    const {
      user,
      password,
      database,
      host,
    } = Object.assign({}, this._params, params);

    this._pool = new Pool({
      user,
      password,
      database,
      host,
    });

    ['SIGHUP', 'SIGINT', 'SIGQUIT', 'SIGILL', 'SIGTRAP', 'SIGABRT',
        'SIGBUS', 'SIGFPE', 'SIGUSR1', 'SIGSEGV', 'SIGUSR2', 'SIGTERM'
    ].forEach(function (sig) {
        process.on(sig, async () => {

          logger.log(`Exiting for ${sig}...`);
          process.exit(0);
        });
    });

    return this;
  }

  async stop () {
    return this._pool.end();
  }

  runQuery (queryString, params=[]) {
    return params.length ? this._pool.query(queryString, params) : this._pool.query(queryString);
  }
};
```

Now to mock it out, you can simply extend your custom class in your test file:

```
const DatabaseInterop = require('/path/to/database_interop.js');
class MockDB extends DatabaseInterop {

    connect () {
      // no-op
    }

    runQuery (qs, ...params) {
      // return whatever
    }

    stop () {
      // noop
    }
}
```

Now for your tests you can inject the mock and your actual system inject the actual interface.

Comment: Thank you for your time! Unfortunately, I could not be able to verify the answer by now. Since I have been using Django after that project have gone.